# Why do we change the order?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, words, shema, bircas-krias-shema

In the brochos before the Shema we have the in [הַמֵּאִיר לָאָרֶץ](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Blessings_of_the_Shema%2C_First_Blessing_before_Shema.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) the phrase  וּבְטוּבו מְחַדֵּשׁ בְּכָל יום תָּמִיד מַעֲשֵׂה בְרֵאשִׁית with the word וּבְטוּבו the first word in that phrase. We then go a bit further on before Ahavah Rabbah, [Lakel Boruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz%2C_Weekday%2C_Shacharit%2C_Blessings_of_the_Shema%2C_First_Blessing_before_Shema.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) towards the end of the bracha we say this familiar phrase as well הַמְחַדֵּשׁ בְּטוּבו בְּכָל יום תָּמִיד מַעֲשה בְרֵאשִׁית but the order of מְחַדֵּשׁ and בְּטוּבו are switched.
Is there a reason why there are switched?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The change in the order does not affect the meaning, but it does change the emphasis. In this case the emphasis would be on the first word.

In the beginning of *Yotzer ohr* we want to talk about his praise in general. We are praising him that he renews the world purely from his goodness.

In the end of *Yotzer ohr* we are praising him from the perspective of the creations. We have more praise and appreciation for this that he renews us every day.

> כלומר: בתחילה מודגש גדולתו של הקב"ה מצד עצמו, ואחר כך איך שהקב"ה מאיר ופועל אצלו כו' באופן אישי כנאמר - שם "פועל גבורות", "עושה חדשות", "מצמיח ישועות", "בורא רפואות" וכו'.‏

פרדס ישעיהו - חלק ד' - פניני תפלה, עמוד 91
https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&pagenum=91&book=618082